# Fit M.2 SSD into a laptop without M.2 port

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, lenovo-laptop

My most recent laptop has broken beyond repair and I'm left with a large M.2 SSD (Crucial M500), which I'd like to reuse in the replacement laptop.

The "new" laptop (say ThinkPad W520 or T430) doesn't have an M.2 connector as far as I know, so is there some possibility to install this M.2 SSD into that laptop?

Maybe a 2.5" housing that will fit the M.2 SSD? Or would my best bet be selling the M.2 SSD and purchasing a regular 2.5" one?

Comment: NB just found this on Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Syba-mSATA-2-5-Inch-Adapter-SY-ADA40050/dp/B007PPZ2I8

Comment: That's for mSATA not M.2, they are not compatible.

Comment: You need something like this: http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-Adapter-Converter-Frame-Housing/dp/B00ITJ7U20.